# Android element fixed positioning

Tags: java, android, android-layout, tablerow

Suppose am having a tablerow and inside that tablerow am having 3 elements (ImageViews).

In the first case all the 3 items have visibility value VISIBLE .Suppose am making an element's visibility to GONE. Then at that case what happens is the other 2 items get adjusted to the missed once place.

But what i want is i need to be all items in a fixed position. So if am making any item's visibility to GONE state, then at that case also the remaining elements be in the same place.

Can anyone help me to achieve this.?

Answer (score 0):

Use `stretchcolumns` in layout and in every `ImageView` specify `layout_span` and `layout_column`..

Comment: can u be more specific ..or can u just provide any useful links.

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this out,
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:stretchColumns="1" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/topbg" >

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="0"
                android:layout_span="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="1"
                android:layout_span="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />

            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_span="1"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i think you didn't get what i mean. In this case also the same thing will happen what i have..

Answer (score 0):

If you want more and more flexibility with your items always try to go for relative layout, hope you can easily solve your issue by using relative layout. You can do whatever you want with your items dynamically or statically both.